# Ingestion of Large Amount of Data in Postgres Slow and Eventually Crashes

Tags: python, postgresql

I've tried to ingest a large amount of data (abour 100 csv files with 15 million rows each) with a `Python` script using the `Luigi` framework and the ingestion was going fine until I reached the following error (from Postgres logs), of which the most important part is:

`2016-08-18 13:14:31.714 UTC,,,8508,,57b5b2ec.213c,1,,2016-08-18 13:06:52 UTC,13/109,0,PANIC,53100,"could not write to file ""pg_xlog/xlogtemp.8508"": No space left on device",,,,,"writing block 49526 of relation base/16384/22811",,,,     ""`

It seems like ingestion is blocked by POSTGRES due to Write Ahead Logging (WAL) mechanism. After having ingested 10 days worth of file and reseting the database I attempted to ingest more days. The second attempt, resulted in only 1 additional day worht of data being ingested. A third attempt just fails entirely.

Is it the case that pg_xlog is not being cleaned? I have no idea of how they are managed and what's the exact purpose, my intuition says that WAL is a mechanism through which POSTGRES writes the lines to be inserted in the database.

Is there any database configuration which I'm missing out? Is it a problem with indexes on my table? What else?

Other sections of the log which might be relevant:

`2016-08-18 12:57:45.255 UTC,,,8342,,57b5a460.2096,96,,2016-08-18 12:04:48 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"checkpoints are occurring too frequently (25 seconds apart)",,"Consider increasing the configuration parameter ""max_wal_size"".",,,,,,,""
2016-08-18 12:57:45.255 UTC,,,8342,,57b5a460.2096,97,,2016-08-18 12:04:48 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"checkpoint starting: xlog",,,,,,,,,""
2016-08-18 12:58:13.609 UTC,,,8342,,57b5a460.2096,98,,2016-08-18 12:04:48 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"checkpoint complete: wrote 349100 buffers (16.6%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 143 removed, 0 recycled; write=15.550 s, sync=12.677 s, t     otal=28.354 s; sync files=51, longest=2.304 s, average=0.248 s; distance=2641771 kB, estimate=2641771 kB",,,,,,,,,""
1038 2016-08-18 12:58:13.610 UTC,,,8342,,57b5a460.2096,99,,2016-08-18 12:04:48 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"checkpoints are occurring too frequently (28 seconds apart)",,"Consider increasing the configuration parameter ""max_wal_size"".",,,,,,,""
1039 2016-08-18 12:58:13.610 UTC,,,8342,,57b5a460.2096,100,,2016-08-18 12:04:48 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"checkpoint starting: xlog",,,,,,,,,""`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the overall size, in GB, of those .csv files?
What is the maximum size of a .csv file?
That's a valuable information for me.

Also, is important to know your execution environment:

- Operating system: Linux, ...
- Storage: NAS, SAN, HDD, SSD, available storage space, ...
- Amount of RAM
- Processor: speed, ...
- PG version: 9.5, ...

I see what is https://github.com/spotify/luigi, but I think is irrelevant in
your problem.
I must suppose that you are coping the .csv files into the PG tables with the
"copy" (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html,
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html) command?

The cause of the problem is clear: is not possible to write into file
because there is no space left on device, because the disk is full due
to the amount of data intented to store.

For a deep explanation of the WAL, see this PG doc chapter:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/wal-intro.html
In short: 
WAL is a method for ensuring data integrity. With WAL, the changes to data files 
    (where tables and indexes reside) are written only AFTER those changes have been
    logged (as sequence of meta-instructions describing the changes) and have been
    flushed to permanent storage. So, in the event of a crash, we will be able to
    recover the database using the log: any changes that have not been applied to the
    data pages can be redone from the log records (this is a "roll-forward recovery", 
    also known as REDO).

You can reset the WAL with the "pg_resetxlog" program. This is explained here:
http://www.hivelogik.com/blog/?p=513
    Postgresql: how to clean pg_xlog
http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/09/pgxlog-disk-space-problem-on-postgres.html
    Solving pg_xlog out of disk space problem on Postgres
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgresetxlog.html
    pg_resetxlog -- reset the write-ahead log and other control information of a PostgreSQL database cluster

Again, in the log trace
    "checkpoints are occurring too frequently (25 seconds apart)",
    "Consider increasing the configuration parameter ""max_wal_size""."
is pointed the solution: 
    increase the configuration parameter "max_wal_size"
In the following link
    https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117479/checkpoints-are-occurring-too-frequently-during-pg-restore
there is more information about something with your same problem.
In that link it says that "...loading a large amount of data into PostgreSQL will cause
checkpoints to occur more often than the normal checkpoint frequency".

Finally, I have some experience ingesting data files (CSV and plain text files)
into PG and I recommend you the following pipeline:

1. Create a temporary table, "MyTargetTmpTable", as UNLOGGED becase data written to unlogged tables
   is not written to the write-ahead log.
2. Truncate the table "MyTargetTmpTable".
3. Divide the input data into batches of a limited maximum size (use the Linux commands
   "cat", "head", etc. "tail") and feed it into the "psql" command which will execute a
   "copy.
   $ cat hugefile.csv | head -n 800000 | psql ... -c "\copy MyTargetTmpTable from pstdin with (format csv)"
4. Move all the rows from "MyTargetTmpTable" to the final table.
5. Repeat all the previous procedure with the remaining CSV rows batches.

Comment: @roger-dieirton thanks for all the valuable information. It clarifies a lot of points regarding large `csv` ingestions to a `postgres` database. As you pointed out the main issue with the ingestion was the lack of space in the device. I had a Linux operating system with two partitions: one for the user's space and the other for the data. I was trying to save the database in the user's space and I was indeed running out of space without realizing it. Once I moved it to the data partition I had no problems with the ingestion.